# Adding location to the URL path in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name xyx.com;


    location /name/ {
        rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
}
}
```

The above link works well if its just **location /** but with any other path like above **location /name/** it fails.

We want the location path to be part of the url when requested.

All xyz.com/name url (and dependent) should proxy/redirect the users to   http://127.0.0.1:80/name

Tried proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1$request_uri and other few stuff including rewrite and it didn't work.

Any suggestions appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    ......
    ...... stuff

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://Client;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    }

    location /identity/ {
            proxy_pass http://Identity/;

            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    }

}

upstream Client{
        zone Client 64k;
        server localhost:5001;
}



upstream Identity{

        zone Identity 64k;
        server localhost:9001;
}
```

example.com ===> my client project
example.com/identity ===> my identity project

**NOTE:** some times you may have to define the original url in your project middleware pipeline. in my case i configure identity server and it generates urls. i have to add below in my middleware pipeline to understood it that your origin base url is example.com/identity/ so the urls must generate base on this base url.(.net core)

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("example.com/identity/");
    
    await next();
});
```